# Extendscript write to stdout or stderr

Tags: extendscript

I'm running an Adobe After Effects project via subprocessing and I'm trying to find a way to write to Stdout or Stderr from within AE, so that I can communicate to the parent process. In other words, is there any way to write to Stdout from Extendscript?
Yes I do know about $.writeln() but that writes to the Extendscript Toolkit console, not stdout and is therefore unreadable by another process.

Comment: can you write to a file and have the other process read that?

Comment: Yeah, that's what was thinking to do. It's obviously a bit of a hack, but it has worked for me in the past... The stupid thing is I swear I figured this out a year or so ago for another project but I can't remember what I did! So I'm pretty sure it is at least possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but you could try using a named pipe instead of a file

Answer (score 1):

A little late but yes. There is a writeConsole() global function... So you use that instead of the one within $. Also there are write() and writeLn() global functions that write to info panel.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to test this out soon. Been meaning to revisit that code again anyway.